# SAAJ0511: Unable to create envelope from given source

Tags: java, web-services, spring-boot, soap, payload

I'm new to spring boot and web services and am trying to create a `soap` webservice, I followed a tutorial but i keep getting the below error:

`SAAJ0511: Unable to create envelope from given source`

the code snippet is as below:

thats the `xsd` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        targetNamespace="http://www.binarystorage.com/binary-storage-soap"
        xmlns:tns="http://www.binarystorage.com/binary-storage-soap"
        elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <element name="store-request" type="tns:binaryData"/>
    <element name="store-response" type="tns:idBody"/>
    <element name="retrieve-request" type="tns:idBody"/>
    <element name="retrieve-response" type="tns:binaryData"/>
    <element name="remove-request" type="tns:idBody"/>
    <element name="remove-response"/>
    <complexType name="binaryData">
        <sequence>
            <element name="name" type="string"/>
            <element name="content" type="string"/>
            <element name="content-type" type="string"/>
            <element name="meta" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <complexType>
                    <attribute name="key" type="string"></attribute>
                    <attribute name="value" type="string"></attribute>
                </complexType>
            </element>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
    <complexType name="idBody">
        <sequence>
            <element name="id" type="string"/>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</schema>
```

and the screen shot below is my try for an endpoint :

[image: thats the endpoint]

Please advice

Thanks

Comment: What tutorial? Also, it could help if you add some code and the error as text

Comment: a tutorial on udemy, and for the code its a simple class you can find it on the screen shot attached on the question, please tell me if you need any specific code,  pardon my bad english